# Jquery pass parameter from script tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables, parameter-passing

Hi guys I just want to know is there any possibility to pass variables from

```
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

this tag? I mean something like this:

```
<script src="js/scripts.js">$par = "hello world"</script>
or
<script src="js/scripts.js" par="hello world"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly should this do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What kind of parameter do you mean? Pass from where to where?

Comment: You're thinking in terms of PHP. In Javascript, if you create a global variable, all scripts can automatically see it, no matter which script you declare it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to or use of defining a variable like you do.

Try this:

```
<script>var par = "<?php echo $par; ?>"</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do both (why you would want this is another question).

Regarding the first option, you'll find a more detailed explanation in [this article from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/).

As for the second option, take a look at the [dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org), they use it a lot (they call it the declarative approach).

Comment: +1 for the link to that resig article. i rather enjoyed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var par = "<?php echo $par; ?>";
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

The variable "par" is then accessible inside the script.